# How do methods work?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I'm still a beginner in Java, and still haven't found a tutorial that explain well to me how classes and methods work. What i mean is, lets say you have 2 classes. The first class has the main method, and another random method.The second has 2 methods that do (Insert whatever you want here). You then create an object of the second class in the 1st one, and call the first method that it has.

```
2nclass.imWithStupid();
```

Will the 2nd class now do all the methods that it has simultaneously, one by one, or nothing until told to do otherwise?

Comment: What do you mean "do all the methods"?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: @KorayTugay I mean run all the methods in that class. As in it will do every single method in that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample class. Check the comments....

```
public class A{
    void m1()
    {
        .....

        B b=new B();
        b.m1() ; //will call only method m1 in B
        b.m2() ; //will call only method m2 in B

        b.callAll() ;  //will call both m1 and m2 method in B

        ....
    }
}



public class B
{

    void m1()
    {
        ....
    }


    void m2()
    {
        ....
    }


    void callAll()
    {
        m1();
        m2();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped significantly!